# Load specific html page with href and GET request response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First, I think my title isn't very clear and very representative of what I want to achieve, but I couldn't make it clearer ...

Ok so I have a `Leaderboard`, created from this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/handler',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        var tb = document.getElementById('Leaderboard');
        while(tb.rows.length > 1) {
          tb.deleteRow(1);
        };
        var keys = Object.keys(data);
        for( key of keys) {
          var username = data[key].username;
          var score = data[key].score;
          var row = $('<tr id = "row' + tb.rows.length + '"><td><a href="/leaderboard/'+ username + '" target="_blank">' + username + '</a></td><td>' + score + '</td></tr>');
          $('#Leaderboard').append(row);
          if(tb.rows.length > 11){
            tb.deleteRow(tb.rows.length -1);
          }
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
      }
  });
```

So as you can see in the `Leaderboard`, when clicking on a username, it opens a new page with the result of a GET request (`/leaderboard/:username`). My question is how can I `skin` this page, or even better load an html file in this page, but while keeping accessible the result of the GET request to use it inside?
That may not be clear, and that's maybe a reason why my title is not really fitting ... But anyway if you have some ideas i'll take them !!
Thanks

Comment: what is learderboad? and do you want to load the new page by ajax call? is that you mean?

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you mean. You click the username link, the new page opens...then what? What do you mean by "skin"? You mean you want it to have the same CSS as the leaderboard page? And what about "load an html file in this page, but while keeping accessible the result of the GET request to use it inside". Which page do you refer to as "this" page in that sentence? Are you talking about having another ajax call within the username page? Or you want to load the username page into the leaderboard page via ajax?

Comment: "My question is how can i "skin" this page, or even better load an html file in this page, but while keeping accessible the result of the GET request to use it inside ?" This is not clear. Can you please elaborate more??

Comment: I think what he means is that he has no idea how to create the new page (and design it) where he can access the GET value. In simple words: He needs to create a PHP (or some other server side language) file. Or mess around with htaccess mod rewrite, but I'm afraid that will just complicate things.

Comment: Yeah i knew it wasn't clear  ... :')

Comment: So the path /leaderboard/:username is a GET request to my server, which looks into a database, finds ( or not) the user and sends back a response (JSON object). The actual way it is done here is when i click on the name, it opens a new window and shows only the object returned by the server. What i want to be able to do is, instead of just opening a window with the object, opening an html file (maybe) in which i can use the object sent back by the server to make something more "presentable" than just a raw JSON object

Comment: what about getting the data via ajax (just like you do with the leaderboard) and display it in a new area of your existing page, e.g. another div, or a popup?

Comment: Well there are 2 solutions. 1) Instead of a hyperlink, create a second Ajax request function that loads the JSON object into a variable and do something with it. Maybe display some overlay div with the info? Or 2) Create a PHP file. Open the file like `<a href='file.php?user=username>` and use PHP `<?php $_GET['user']; ?>` to retrieve the json and build a page with it.

Comment: @ADyson I thought about that, but that's not really what i wanted ... It may be a last-hope solution if the rest is not possible

Comment: If you know nothing about PHP, I'm willing to help you out and create something nice. But that would be way to much work to do here on Stack Overflow. So if that's the case, let me know and we'll work something out.

Comment: so there are two other possibilities. 1) Create another HTML file. The hyperlink loads your new _HTML file_, not the JSON. When the HTML file opens the first thing it does is fetch the username JSON data (it would collect the exact username from the querystring passed to the HTML and pass that on to the ajax call). 2) Do something serverside with PHP which gets the same data as is returned as JSON, but instead of returning JSON it uses the data to build some HTML to display

Comment: @icecub yeah i think your php file method i what i wanted to achieve, do you have any idea where i can find some examples to follow for this ?

Comment: Thanks @icecub, very nice from you, because i kinda know nothing about php...

Comment: @ADyson i think the PHP method seem the more adapted to what i want, i'll try to figure it out ! Thank you for your responses :)

Comment: Alright. I have a script on my website that allowes us both to work toghether on your code. (Something called Operational Transformation). All you have to do is put your code into a ZIP file and upload it there. You will be taken to some sort of chatroom where we can talk and we can both work at your code. Sounds cool?

Comment: Sounds cool ! what's your site ?

Comment: You don't have to include all your code of course. Just the relevent files is enough. Like 1 JSON user file and the file that contains the script above should be enough :)

Comment: You can upload it here: http://home.icecub.nl/PairProgramming/ - Read carefully because it explains what you need to do. Once you're inside, click the invite button and comment the URL here so I know where to go. Don't type anything into the site yet! The empty field you're seeing is known to break stuff.

Comment: here is the link : http://home.icecub.nl/PairProgramming/project.php?id=601622434#&togetherjs=Qk9hyd9ICA

Comment: @icecub Well i come back kinda immediatly, the php link doesn't work, when clickink the href link it downloads the php file instead if using it

Comment: Awww, yes. I didn't check if you actually have PHP running on your server. Without PHP installed on the server, you can't run PHP files of course

Comment: Oh yes ok, I'll enable it, didn't thought about that ...

Comment: @icecub, sent you an email ! :)